# É possível instalar o Koel em servidor php simples?

Tags: php, laravel, composer, hospedagem, configuração

Queria saber se é possível instalar o [Koel](https://github.com/phanan/koel),
em um servidor PHP simples, hospedagem básica. Se sim, como posso instalar corretamente ?

Comment: O servidor suporta lavavel, nodejs e npm?

Comment: laravel sim, já nodejs não sei dizer acredito que não

Comment: não suporta nodejs